# Provide Internet To Two Networks One Connection

Tags: networking, routing, vlan

Currently we have one network set to 192.168.1.x and is set via DHCP providing internet to all machines on that network.

Recently we've began development on programmable logic controllers that are on a 192.168.92.x network.

The problem is that I need to have the controllers communicating to the internet.

Could I just change the gateways in the controllers to 192.168.1.1 and leave the other settings?  Or would I need to invest in a router that has vlan capabilities?  I want to keep the controllers on the 192.168.92.x network.  I'm just not sure if I can achieve this via software or a hardware solution.

Comment: Can you expand on what you have? This is pretty simple to achieve but we need details about your infrastructure. What is your current router? Are you a Windows or Linux shop? How many end points? What network gear / switches do you have?

Comment: Giving us the network address without the subnet mask is like giving us a house address without a street name. Can the 192.168.92.x addresses connect to the gateway at 192.168.1.x? Sure, given the correct subnet mask.

Comment: The current network is about 15 computers (Macs and PCs) and cell phones.  The router we use now is just a Linksys E4200.  We do have a few unmanaged switches around the network.

The subnet is 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you need a router, layer 3 switch or a computer with 3 network interfaces. Or, two, if you can connect that to a managed switch with vlan capabilities*. Beyond that, you either need to separate the two networks physically or use more switches with vlans.

*look up the term 'router on a stick'